# ¿Cómo hacer para que puedan enviarme adjuntos a través de mi formulario de contacto?

Tags: php

Tengo un inconveniente con el envío de imágenes o adjuntos a través de mi página, me gustaría que las personas que completan mi formulario y quieran enviarme alguna imagen, puedan hacerlo desde ahí mismo, actualmente el botón está, selecciona el archivo, pero lógicamente, el mail me llega solo con la información.

Mi página es la siguiente: http://indgraphicdesign.com.ar/contacto.html

Mi código PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(-1);


// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // Edita las dos líneas siguientes con tu dirección de correo y asunto personalizados

    $email_to = "
 ind.graphicdesign@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Mail de la página";   

    function died($error) {

        // si hay algún error, el formulario puede desplegar su mensaje de aviso

        echo "Lo sentimos, hubo un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado en este momento. ";

        echo "Detalle de los errores.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Porfavor corrija estos errores e inténtelo de nuevo.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // Se valida que los campos del formulairo estén llenos

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['message'])) {

        died('Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.');       

    }
 //En esta parte el valor "name" nos sirve para crear las variables que recolectaran la información de cada campo

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // requerido

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // requerido

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // requerido

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // no requerido 

    $message = $_POST['message']; // requerido

    $error = ""; //Linea numero 52

//En esta parte se verifica que la dirección de correo sea válida 

   $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'La dirección de correo proporcionada no es válida.<br />';

  }

//En esta parte se validan las cadenas de texto

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'El formato del nombre no es válido<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'el formato del apellido no es válido.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($message) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'El formato del texto no es válido.<br />';

  }



//A partir de aqui se contruye el cuerpo del mensaje tal y como llegará al correo

    $email_message = "Contenido del Mensaje.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "Nombre: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Apellido: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Teléfono: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Mensaje: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


//Se crean los encabezados del correo

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- incluye aqui tu propio mensaje de Éxito-->

Gracias! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo a la brevedad


<?php

}

?>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Para entender que es lo que sucede primero recomiendo leer la documentación sobre [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php).

Tomando en cuenta que en tu formulario, el campo (input) de tipo "file" tiene el nombre "upload".

```
<input type="file" name="upload" multiple />
```

Al recibir dos archivos tendríamos una estructura parecida a:

```
array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        [0]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file0.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/plain" 
        }, 
        [1]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file1.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/html" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Debes incluir las cabeceras:

```
$separator = md5(time());

// attachment
$headers .= "--" . $_FILE['name']['tmp_name'] . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= $content . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "--" . $separator . "--";
```

Fuente oficial: [Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail).

---

Mi recomendación es que uses **PHPMailer**, el proceso es sencillo, menos código (por tanto engorroso), seguro y mantenido por la comunidad con amplia experiencia. De usarlo quedaría tu código algo como lo siguiente:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = $email_from;
$email->FromName  = 'Tu nombre';
$email->Subject   = $email_subject;
$email->Body      = $email_message;
$email->AddAddress($email_to);

foreach ($_FILES['upload'] as $file) {
    $email->AddAttachment($file['tmp_name'] , 'nombre_archivo_opcional.pdf');
}

$email->Send();
```

- [PHPMailer tutorial](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, traté de implementar tanto lo del array como lo de las cabeceras, pero me devuelve error en la linea de array y ya no salen los mails directamente, podrias indicarme como incluir lo que me pasas en mi código, porque evidentemente no lo estoy haciendo correctamente, de php se practicamente nada. Gracias

Comment: ¿Con PHPMailer no te funciona?.

Comment: Perdon @Chofoteddy , agregue los tres fragmentos de código que me pasaste, pero el mail me llega a mi correo solo con la info del formulario, sin la imagen que cargo para mandar. Me devuelve el mensaje de enviado correctamente.

Comment: Perdon @Chofoteddy , reemplaze mal el archivo en el servidor, agregue los tres fragmentos de código que me pasaste, pero me devuelve este mensaje al enviar con la imagen:" syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/nico1gnr/public_html/send_form_email.php on line 131"
La línea 131 seria la siguiente:

'array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        [0]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file0.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/plain" 
        }, 
        [1]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file1.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/html" 
        } 
    } 
}'

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo bajé una vez de una web y me ayudó:

**formulario.html**

```
<form name='formulario' id='formulario' method='post' action='enviar.php' target='_self' enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<p>Nombre <input type='text' name='Nombre' id='Nombre'></p> 
<p>E-mail 
<input type='text' name='email' id='email'> 
</p> 
<p>Asunto 
<input type='text' name='asunto' id='asunto' /> 
</p> 
<p>Mensaje 
<textarea name="mensaje" cols="50" rows="10" id="mensaje"></textarea> 
</p> 
<p>Adjuntar archivo: <input type='file' name='archivo1' id='archivo1'></p> 
<p> 
<input type='submit' value='Enviar'> 
</p> 
</form>
```

**enviar.php:**

```
<?php 
function form_mail($sPara, $sAsunto, $sTexto, $sDe) 
{ 
$bHayFicheros = 0; 
$sCabeceraTexto = ""; 
$sAdjuntos = ""; 

if ($sDe)$sCabeceras = "From:".$sDe."n"; 
else $sCabeceras = ""; 
$sCabeceras .= "MIME-version: 1.0n"; 
foreach ($_POST as $sNombre => $sValor) 
$sTexto = $sTexto."n".$sNombre." = ".$sValor; 

foreach ($_FILES as $vAdjunto) 
{ 
if ($bHayFicheros == 0) 
{ 
$bHayFicheros = 1; 
$sCabeceras .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;"; 
$sCabeceras .= "boundary="--_Separador-de-mensajes_--"n"; 

$sCabeceraTexto = "----_Separador-de-mensajes_--n"; 
$sCabeceraTexto .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1n"; 
$sCabeceraTexto .= "Content-transfer-encoding: 7BITn"; 

$sTexto = $sCabeceraTexto.$sTexto; 
} 
if ($vAdjunto["size"] > 0) 
{ 
$sAdjuntos .= "nn----_Separador-de-mensajes_--n"; 
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-type: ".$vAdjunto["type"].";name="".$vAdjunto["name"].""n";; 
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64n"; 
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-disposition: attachment;filename="".$vAdjunto["name"].""nn"; 

$oFichero = fopen($vAdjunto["tmp_name"], 'r'); 
$sContenido = fread($oFichero, filesize($vAdjunto["tmp_name"])); 
$sAdjuntos .= chunk_split(base64_encode($sContenido)); 
fclose($oFichero); 
} 
} 

if ($bHayFicheros) 
$sTexto .= $sAdjuntos."nn----_Separador-de-mensajes_----n"; 
return(mail($sPara, $sAsunto, $sTexto, $sCabeceras)); 
} 


if (form_mail("email@receptor.com", $_POST[asunto], 
"Los datos introducidos en el formulario son:nn", $_POST[email])) 
echo "Su formulario ha sido enviado con exito"; 
?>
```

Recuerdo que mejoré los `$__POST["email"]` con `if (isset($_POST["email"])){...}` pero solo encontré el código original que bajé , no el que arregle. De todas formas te va a servir.

Comment: Gracias Eduardo por la rápida respuesta, traté de implementarlo, pero en php soy muy novato, no supe implementar tu código en el mio, me devuelve un error, podrías decirme dónde lo tengo que incluir exactamente o si tengo q reemplazar una parte del que ya tengo? gracias nuevamente